# Limit the file extensions displayed in Google Drive on Android app

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am allowing users of my Android app to take their own photos or use photos from their gallery and one aspect of that is that they can open Google Drive too.  Is there any way to open Google Drive and only show files that are images?

I haven't been able to find anything on this online but I would imagine something like this is possible.  Otherwise I have to handle incorrect file types on the app side which is an okay solution but I was hoping to prevent the problem on the user side in addition to handling the incorrect file types.

Comment: What do you mean by "open Google Drive".  Are you just getting a list of files?

Comment: My application opens the Google Drive application and lets the user select a file to upload.